# Change tmux local time

Tags: tmux, timezone

I'm working on a Linux server who is in a different time zone than me.

How can I make tmux display, in the status bar, my local time, instead of the server local time (without messing up the server time)?

For info, I'm using tmux 3.1

Comment: Have you considered just setting `TZ=` the wanted timezone in your login on the remote, so that all times are shown as local? (see `man timezone` for TZ values).

Comment: I do now, and it works, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use on your `~/.tmux.conf` the following setting:

```
set -g status-right '[#(TZ="America/New_York" date +"%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M")]'
```